# Extract all rows of an specific columns with respect to another column in pandas DataFrame()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Apologies** if this questions seems very easy in advance!

Given the following small dataset `pd.DataFrame()`:

```
    userId  movieId     rating
0   1       169         2.5
1   1       2471        3.0
2   1       48516       5.0
3   2       2571        3.5
4   2       109487      4.0
5   2       112552      5.0
6   2       112556      4.0
7   3       356         4.0
8   3       2394        4.0
9   3       2431        5.0
```

I would like to extract all the `movieId` that one user with `userId` has watched!
The output for the above dataset I expect to get is something like this:

```
[[169, 2471, 48516], [2571, 109487, 112552, 112556], [356, 2394, 2431]]
```

I have written a for loop which results different than what I expected and seems **extremely** inefficient as the size of the dataset increases:

```
mv_lst = []
usrID = np.unique(test_df['userId'])
for i,v in enumerate( test_df['userId'] ):
    if v in usrID:
        mv_lst.append(test_df['movieId'][i])
print(mv_lst)
# result: [169, 2471, 48516, 2571, 109487, 112552, 112556, 356, 2394, 2431]
```

Is there smarter and cleaner alternative in pandas to do this?
Cheers,

Comment: `df.groupby('userID')['movieId'].agg(list)`

Comment: Use `L = test_df.groupby('userID')['movieId'].apply(list).tolist()`